# Publishing my first GAS, API trust & safety is ok, API Gsuite Marketplace is reviewed?

Tags: google-apps-script, publishing

I have received a mail from Google trust and safety team: "request granted" so my App will be publishing, but if I see in Gsuite Marketplace SDK API is reviewed. Is It right and so I have just to wait or I have to do something?

Comment: You can add a comment on the Google docs shared by docs addon advisor. Say that oAuth access been granted. They will notification about it. And soon your addon will be published.

Comment: what's "docs addon advisor"? Where I find it?